# Changing line draw length when changing chart resolution?

Tags: pine-script

[PINE SCRIPT] Hoping someone might be able to help me, trying to adjust line.new for differing length amounts corresponding to the resolution of the chart aka 1 minute chart 810 for example but changing to a 5 min chart will change length to 695 etc. Banging my head against the wall and hope someone amazing might be able to point me in the correct direction. Cheers :)

```
EXT_look

//Length Lookup inputs
len_1mMKT               =   390             //1dayMTK
len_1mEXT               =   810             //1DAYEXT
len_2m                  =   810             //2DAYEXT
len_3m                  =   810             //3DAY EXT
len_5m                  =   695             //5day EXT
len_15m                 =   249             //5DAY
len_30m                 =   497             //30DAY
len_45m                 =   376             //4MONTHS
len_60m                 =   686             //3MONTHS
len_120m                =   734             //6MTHS
len_180m                =   734             //3MTH
len_240m                =   720             //4MTH      
len_D                   =   254             //1Y
len_W                   =   156             //3YR
len_M                   =   61              //5YRS
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Length Variable set
Resolution     = input("", "Resolution", input.resolution)
EXT_look = show_EXT ? len_1mEXT : len_1mMKT


len_length = (input.resolution == "1") ? EXT_look :
     (input.resolution == "2") ? len_2m :
     (input.resolution == "3") ? len_3m :
     (input.resolution == "5") ? len_5m :
     (input.resolution == "15") ? len_15m :
     (input.resolution == "30") ? len_30m :
     (input.resolution == "45") ? len_45m :
     (input.resolution == "60") ? len_60m :
     (input.resolution == "120") ? len_120m :
     (input.resolution == "180") ? len_180m :
     (input.resolution == "240") ? len_240m :
     (input.resolution == "D") ? len_D :
     (input.resolution == "W") ? len_W :
     (input.resolution == "M") ? len_M :
         810
plot(len_length)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare the `input.resolution` with an integer as it defines the type of the input variable.

In your `len_length` you should compare the `Resolution` variable instead.

```
//Length Lookup inputs
len_1mMKT               =   390             //1dayMTK
len_1mEXT               =   810             //1DAYEXT
len_2m                  =   810             //2DAYEXT
len_3m                  =   810             //3DAY EXT
len_5m                  =   695             //5day EXT
len_15m                 =   249             //5DAY
len_30m                 =   497             //30DAY
len_45m                 =   376             //4MONTHS
len_60m                 =   686             //3MONTHS
len_120m                =   734             //6MTHS
len_180m                =   734             //3MTH
len_240m                =   720             //4MTH      
len_D                   =   254             //1Y
len_W                   =   156             //3YR
len_M                   =   61              //5YRS
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Length Variable set
Resolution     = input("60", "Resolution", input.resolution)
EXT_look = show_EXT ? len_1mEXT : len_1mMKT

len_length = (Resolution == "1") ? EXT_look :
     (Resolution == "2") ? len_2m :
     (Resolution == "3") ? len_3m :
     (Resolution == "5") ? len_5m :
     (Resolution == "15") ? len_15m :
     (Resolution == "30") ? len_30m :
     (Resolution == "45") ? len_45m :
     (Resolution == "60") ? len_60m :
     (Resolution == "120") ? len_120m :
     (Resolution == "180") ? len_180m :
     (Resolution == "240") ? len_240m :
     (Resolution == "D") ? len_D :
     (Resolution == "W") ? len_W :
     (Resolution == "M") ? len_M :
         810
plot(len_length)
```